# trying to showup email with setDataToView but the user email does'nt showup on EditText, why?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

**UPDATE**

the problem is i cant show up user email on EditText

i tried to put onStart and onStop mauth listener and then when i run the app and enter this activity the user see as null and kick me back to login activity. so is there any solution on this ?

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText newEmail;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mauthListener;
    private FirebaseAuth mauth;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        //get current user
        final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        //get firebase auth instance
        mauth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        newEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email1);

        //tracking the sign in and singn out operations
        mauthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user == null) {
                    // user auth state is changed - user is null
                    // launch login activity
                    startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };

        setDataToView();
    }

private void setDataToView() {
final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null){
    newEmail.setText("" + user.getEmail());
```

}
}

**UPDATED**
i cant show up user email on EditText, whats wrong now ?

Comment: what happens exatly?, I only want to know to try help you better.

Comment: i can run my app, but when i enter this activity the app crash, i tried to fix it but didn't get any clue whats wrong, can you help ?

Comment: post the logcat error message here to see what error is happening, thanks

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getEmail()' on a null object reference
this what on logcat

Comment: what you need to do is set hint after get the user and not inside a method, or inside the method get the user and set the hint if you want i can create a detailed answer.

Comment: yea, can you give a detailed answer ?

Comment: @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void setDataToView(FirebaseUser user) {

       // newEmail.setHint("" + user.getEmail());

    }

what wrong in this code ?

Answer (score 0):

So firebase user in your **setDataToView()** is null because you are setting the usermail to Edittext without check if is null to fix that you have two possible ways.

One is do that :

```
mauthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user == null) {
                    // user auth state is changed - user is null
                    // launch login activity
                    startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }else{
                   newEmail.setHint("" + user.getEmail());
                }
            }
        };
```

other way is do that:

```
private void setDataToView() {
    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null){
        newEmail.setHint("" + user.getEmail());
   }
}
```

Comment: ok i tried both way and the app don't crash any more but the email didnt showup in the EditText. any idea why ?

Comment: probably the firebase user is null and because of that the user mail not shows, try to logcat the user.getEmail() to see if the email shows, if not the user is always null. @avid_kupit

Comment: 11-19 23:11:31.371 14993-14993/com.dev.havid.beactive D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
11-19 23:11:31.372 14993-14993/com.dev.havid.beactive D/FirebaseApp: Notified 0 auth state listeners.
   is this what you mean ? i also gues like that to, see my update problem

Comment: I mean log the usermail and not set edittext hint, and see if the mail shows in the logcat.